# how add Id property on array of objects from the api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the data from the API has no id when I try I add an Id property the whole of the objects take  same id, how to make a unique id for every object of the array?
here is my code and a screenshot from the console shows all the objects taking the same id

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const getTasks = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let allTasks = json.results;
        
        const id = nanoid();
       
        allTasks = allTasks.map((currentTask) => {
          return { ...currentTask, isHeld: false, id: id };
        });
        setTasks(allTasks);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tasks);
  }, [tasks]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tasks &&
        tasks.map((task) => {
          return <h1> {task.question}</h1>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: the console and objects having the same id]

Comment: 1) You probably don't need to use nanoid here - as you're setting the id prior to rendering the array of objects. You could probably just use the map index. 2) You're not actually using that id as the key for your todo in your JSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a constant value for id, and setting the same for every entry of the array.

You can change your code, for something like this:

```
const getTasks = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let allTasks = json.results;
       
        allTasks = allTasks.map((currentTask) => {
          const id = nanoid(); // <--- This way every iteration of the map will create a new value to id
          return { ...currentTask, isHeld: false, id: id };
        });
        setTasks(allTasks);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the ID inside the map function as such:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const getTasks = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let allTasks = json.results;
       
        allTasks = allTasks.map((currentTask) => {
          return { ...currentTask, isHeld: false, id: nanoid() };
        });
        setTasks(allTasks);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tasks);
  }, [tasks]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tasks &&
        tasks.map((task) => {
          return <h1> {task.question}</h1>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create id inside map, like this

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

export default function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const getTasks = () => {
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        let allTasks = json.results;
       
        allTasks = allTasks.map((currentTask) => {
          return { ...currentTask, isHeld: false, id: nanoid() };
        });
        setTasks(allTasks);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTasks();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(tasks);
  }, [tasks]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tasks &&
        tasks.map((task) => {
          return <h1> {task.question}</h1>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you create a unique id only once and then assign it to every object in the collection. You need to move a call to `nanoid()` inside the `.map(cb)` callback function.

```
allTasks = allTasks.map((currentTask) => {
  const id = nanoid();
  return { ...currentTask, isHeld: false, id: id };
});
```